# Posting XML in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, xml

How does one post XML in Stack Overflow?

I've tried using `<pre>` and backticks to no avail. I suppose that I could go through and try indent every line by four spaces but that would get really tedious really fast.

Is there any way to easily post XML in a question?

**Edit:**

URL of question: [Configuring ELMAH: Unrecognized config section error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337316/configuring-elmah-unrecognized-config-section-error)

I tried putting the XML inside `<code>` tags and that sliced and diced the XML in a very odd fashion.

Comment: Why not post to where you are having the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just use the code block?

- There is a code button in the editor toolbar: [image]
- You could highlight the XML and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>
- You could indent the XML with 4 spaces.

---

#### Edit:

In your case, you are getting close to exceeding the maximum length of a post. You should be more terse or host it externally.

---

#### Edit:

I fixed your post for you by highlighting the XML and clicking the button like I said.

---

#### More information:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Or Ctrl-K, or use a real text editor to do the indent, or the toolbar button...

Comment: Sorry about that; I thought I had solved it by putting the XML inside a code block only to realize upon re-reading the post that much of the XML had been sliced off.

Comment: If the length has been exceeded, why does it remove a piece in the middle and not cut off the end?

Comment: See edits. OP did not read my post apparently.

Comment: Thats odd, I tried adding 4 spaces, and all it did was move the line numbers over, the XML code still didn't show up in the preview.

Comment: I've read your post several times but I probably missed one of your edit blurbs. Sorry about that. It looks like the XML part is back at last. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Zian: You clearly did not read it. All I did was highlight your stuff and click the code button.

Comment: @Rich B
I thought the code block button simply inserted `<code>` tags. Until I dived into the source code of the post (so to speak), I didn't realize that the code block button inserted spaces.

Comment: Note that in case the XML does not get recognized despite the code block, one can use `<!-- language: lang-xml -->`.

Answer (score 9):

Another potential cause of XML not being displayed correctly is if the code is part of a list; either numerated #) or bulleted -. In this case you need 8 spaces in front of the XML code for it to be escaped instead of the standard 4 spaces.

- For example, unescaped XML:

  Not escaped
- Example, correctly escaped:

  ```
  <style>Correctly escaped</style>
  ```

As described in this post: [Post XML in answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216042/post-xml-in-answer?noredirect=1#comment698906_216042)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216043/332043), for lists, there's also a second way:

- If you have a list, you can use `<!-- -->` to break the formatting

  This is with 4 spaces

```
This is with 4 spaces and an invisible HTML comment
```

Otherwise, lists requires `4 + 4 * indentLevel`  spaces to format properly. It's only critical for HTML, XML, and other tag-based languages, as these are invisible and become post formatting rather than post content. The code formatting of 4 spaces is relative to the current level of indentation. A list has a standard indentation of 4, a list child item has a standard indentation of 8, and so on.

Generally though, CTRL+K or clicking the two brackets on the toolbar is enough. Or, of course, manually indenting everything with 4 (or more) spaces).
Unfortunately, CTRL+K/bracket button doesn't work properly in lists. It just changes it between 0 and 4 spaces, like it's any other code block.

---

With the new code-block formatting using three backticks, it's now possible to format without a comment or additional spaces. Example:

````
* List item

    ```
    Nested code
    ```

```
Separate code
```
````

---

- List item

  ```
  Nested code
  ```

```
Separate code
```

Answer (score -2):

Depending on how much you are trying to post, using an outside repository like PasteBin may be your most efficient method.

Comment: Or he could just use a code block on SO.com and not make external links for no reason.

Comment: Or when the post is too big he could use PasteBin :)