# Post XML in answer

Tags: support, code-formatting

I'm unable to get an XML code sample to be formatted correctly when used as part of a numerated or bulleted list. The XML doesn't format correctly regardless of whether I toggle the 'code formatting' or 'quote' buttons. The tags just don't appear at all and instead, the content outside the tags is show.

Original post: I'm having some trouble formatting some XML correctly in an answer and was wondering if someone could help me out.

URL: [android: set textColor with textAppearance attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225851/android-set-textcolor-with-textappearance-attribute/21104200#21104200)

I've taken a look at this answer which doesn't seem to help: 
[Posting XML in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17940/posting-xml-in-stack-overflow)

I've had to put a full stop (.) in the tags causing problems `<style>` and `<item>`; otherwise they don't appear at all.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You needed more indent - inside lists you need 8 spaces

Comment: @JohnPalmer Make that an answer?

Comment: XML in a code bloock works poorly, makes my post look like garbage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get code formatting inside a list, you need to indent by an extra 4 spaces for a total of 8 spaces.

If you just use 4 spaces, markdown assumes you are continuing the list.